# React Native - Focus Input In FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am rendering a dynamic list according to data from a server. If the *onSubmitEditing* event is firedn the next  component in the FlatList should be focused. I tried using refs to focus the dynamic forms, but it is not working appropriate (the next input is not getting focused). To identify the item in the FlatList the index is used.

```
<FlatList
  ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
  data={this.state.articles}
  renderItem={({item,index}) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  extraData={this.state}
/>

renderItem = (itemData, index) => {
  <TextInput
    ref={'article' + index}
    onSubmitEditing={
      () => {
        let reference = 'article' + (index+1);
        this.refs.reference.focus();
      }
  />
}
```

How can the next field can be focused according to the ref?

Answer (score 0):

To get the next reference use this `this.refs[reference]` to focus try either `.current.focus()` or `.focus()` not sure which one may work.

so your code will be like this `

```
`this.refs[reference].current.focus()` or `this.refs[reference].focus()`
```

Answer (score 0):

**My solutions is:**

```
<TextInput
  autoFocus // <-- add this
/>
```